# TYPO3 Fluid - How To Make f:form.textarea Mandatory

Tags: validation, textarea, typo3, fluid, required

I have text fields like this that will turn red and won't let you submit the form automatically if I put the property `required` on "1":

```
<f:form.textfield required="1" 
                  property="name" 
                  class="lcapp-formwidth"/>
```

Now I'm searching for the same in a textarea...the property `required` doesn't work here anymore...what would be the "best practice" to make it a required field just like the textfield?

```
<f:form.textarea property="story" 
                 rows="3" 
                 cols="7" 
                 class="lcapp-formwidth" />
```

Comment: I don't think f:form.textarea has this property . But you can implement the same thing using an "onclick" attribute.https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Form/TextareaViewHelper.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is true, the TextareaViewHelper does not support the required attribute as an argument, but you can add any attribute to a fluid generated tag by using the `additionalAttributes` argument.

E.g.:

```
<f:form.textarea property="story" 
    rows="3" 
    cols="7" 
    class="lcapp-formwidth"
    additionalAttributes="{required: 'required'}" />
```

Notice how `additionalAttributes` expects an array notation, where the key is the name of the attribute.

Comment: If you want multiple Parameters use the following notation  additionalAttributes="{required: 'required',maxLength:'100'}"